# Doing two COUNT on a single column without using views in one sql statement or in pl/sql block

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have a table attendance having columns
date1 ,status(either PRESENT or ABSENT),student_idstudent and student_subject_subjectid

I want make a query for student_idstudent and percentage attendance they have ie(count of present/total count) for each student for a particular subject.
Essentially I just want the values of two counts. Is there any easy way to do so without using views and preferably using pl/sql?

Below is my try using cursor.

Please tell me whether using the below code is it guaranteed to give corresponding answers(ie present count and total count) for each student_idstudent

Also tell me if this can fail in any other case?

```
    DECLARE 
    s_id attendance.student_idstudent%type; 
    s_present number(3); 
    CURSOR student_present is select student_idstudent, count(student_idstudent) from  attendance 
    where status like 'Present' and student_subject_subjectid like 102 
    group by student_idstudent;

    s1_id attendence.student_idstudent%type; 
    s1_total number(3); 
    CURSOR student_total is select student_idstudent, count(student_idstudent) from attendance 
    where student_subject_subjectid like 102 
    group by student_idstudent;

    BEGIN 
    OPEN student_present; 
    OPEN student_total;
    LOOP 
    FETCH student_present into s_id, s_present;
    FETCH student_total into s1_id, s1_total;
    EXIT WHEN student_present%notfound;  
    dbms_output.put_line('student '|| s_id || ' has ' ||S_present/s1_total*100 || '% record' ); 
    END LOOP; 

    CLOSE student_present; 
    CLOSE student_total; 
    END; 
    /
```

Comment: Don't think you need a cursor or pl/sql proc for this. Try doing it using SQL. If you can then its always better to use SQL instead of PL/sql.

Comment: @vishad: as with all absolute statements (including this one, I suppose :-) there's always a counterexample. I once encountered a huge SQL statement, multiple pages long, that did wonderful things but took forever to do them. The replacement "simple-cursor-and-a-bit-of-logic" was much shorter codewise, and ran in much less time. YMMV.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With @ronnis help.

I came up with this answer.

```
    SELECT student_idstudent,
    count(CASE WHEN  status = 'Present'  then 1 END)/count(*)*100 as percentage
    FROM attendence 
    where student_subject_subjectid = 102
    group by student_idstudent;
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if this is a homework question or not, so Im giving you a partial answer, and you should be able to complete the query on your own.

```
select student_idstudent
      ,count(case when status like 'Absent'  then 1 end) as absent_count
      ,count(case when status like 'Present' then 1 end) as present_count
      ,count(*)                                      as tot_count
  from attendance
 where student_subject_subjectid = 102
 group 
    by student_idstudent;
```

Also, using `LIKE` without any wild card characters is equal to using `=`. For clarity, the conditions should really be written `status = 'Absent'` and `status = 'Present'`. This is also more clear.

The same goes for `like <number>`. Do you mean `student_subject_subjectid = 102`, or do you have something else in mind?

Comment: Thanks @ronnis for the help. I knew that like could be replaced by '='. Also please tell me is it pl/sql or sql

Comment: @mascot6699 my query above is pure SQL.

Comment: I understand that your method is way simpler and I was looking for that only but could you also enlighten me the case where the method written in question could fail. I would really like to know that is that answer full-proof or not.